# Excel, How to write a formula that fits these criteria

Tags: excel

```
     A          B           C           D           E           F           G
1   Date:   9/15/2016   9/16/2016   9/17/2016   9/18/2016   9/19/2016  9/20/2016
2   Points:     0.5         1            -          -           0.5         1
```

The above data is on tab 1 of an excel spread sheet

And below are fields on tab 2 of the same excel spread sheet:

```
     A        B
1   DATE:   Points
2       
3       
4       
5
```

I am trying to write a formula that will go through the dates and points rows on tab 1 and when it finds a date with a corresponding point it will populate that date in tab 2 under the Date column.   Simple enough right? Well here's where I'm running into problems, I need a formula to include the following criteria:

1) If the date does not have a corresponding point in the second row on tab 1 it will skip it and move on to the next date to validate it and so on

*note- I also need the Points column on tab 2 to populate with the corresponding date, but I believe a simple HLOOKUP formula will work just fine

2) I would like to have the formula to where it can be duplicated on tab 2 cells A3,A4,A5 and so on, but as an example: if A2 has date of 9/15/2016, when the formula in A3 is checking for dates with corresponding points in tab 1, it will skip the date in tab 2 located in A2 since it's already been used

Below is a picture of the above data in case it didn't come out right, and thanks for the help!!

Comment: What does this have to do with `xml`?

Comment: I changed it sorry for that, new to this website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Tab1'!$B$1:$G$1,MATCH(1,('Tab1'!$B$2:$G$2<>"")*(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,'Tab1'!$B$1:$G$1)=0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This will create a list as it is dragged/copied done.  The list will be in the same order as the list on tab1.

[image]

Comment: @bordemkills please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Ok, I've tried entering in this formula several times. Once entered I pressed Ctrl-Shift-Enter, I keep getting an Error message that says "You've entered to few arguments for this function"

Comment: @bordemkills please post the exact formula you are trying.  You must be missing something.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('Tab 1'!$C$4:$H$4,MATCH(1,('Tab 1'!$C$5:$H$5<>"")*(COUNTIF($G$6:G6,'Tab 1'!$C$4:$H$4)=0),0)),"")

Comment: My cells are not the same as in the example, i can set it up to where they are if youd like me to

Comment: I get no such error with your formula.  Do you use something different for the delimiter like `;` instead of `,` in your formulas?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I just moved all the data over to match the example I'd given up above. Your formula did work!!! This is a silly question but besides something I did wrong, would there be a reason why it wouldn't work with the data in different cells?

Comment: I'm not sure, I could of been making a silly error. I really appreciate the help Scott!